# I am trying to POST data to from wcf service from android application but getting Error 400. Please help me

Tags: c#, android, wcf

I am creating a wcf service that will be consumed by the android application.

I have declared an interface like:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "RegsiterUser")]
    string RegsiterUser(RegsiterUser rUser);
```

In service code:

```
public string RegsiterUser(RegsiterUser rUser)
{
    return rUser.userName;
}
```

I have created a class:

```
[DataContract]
public class RegsiterUser
{

    #region Property

    [DataMember]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

When this service is called, then it is giving bad request error: 400

I have also tested it using postmaster app of chrome and the same is coming, so if any body has a solution, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the JSON you are sending to the server?

Comment: You'll need to post the details of how you're calling the service, because we can't help you with this.  Can you post your request code?

Answer (score 1):

**Interface**

Since you are using a GET-Method with an Parameter you need to declare that parameter in the UriTemplate:
Get-Methods with a request-body can technically work, but are not recommended:
see this post for more on this topic: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

So you could change the method to POST, and submit a JSON, or work with GET and parameters.

This would be an example for the parameter version:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "getuserdata/{userName}")]
     string RegsiterUser(string userName);
```

If you want POST, just change the Method to POST, the rest looks fine.

**Model**

I would recommend specifying the names of the properties, likes this: This way you get more control over your JSON and it's clear how the properties have to be named.

```
    [DataMember(Name = "userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```